# Nested dictionary from 3 columns, one of which with repeating categories by top-level dictionary key

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

My dataframe:

```
| Name  | Greenhouse Gas | Quantity |
|:------|:--------------:|---------:|
| Chair | Methane        | 0.5      | 
| Chair | CO2            | 0.4      | 
| Chair | Other          | 0.6      | 
| House | Methane        | 0.2      | 
| House | CO2            | 0.4      | 
| House | Other          | 0.3      |
```

Trying to get output:

```
{Name:{Methane:#, CO2:#, Other:#},Name:{Methane:#, CO2:#, Other:#}}
```

E.g.

```
{Chair:{Methane: 0.5, CO2: 0.4, Other:0.6},House:{Methane:0.2, CO2:0.4, Other: 0.3}}
```

Have tried:

```
df.groupby('Name')[['Greenhouse Gas','Quantity']].apply(lambda x: x.set_index('Greenhouse Gas').to_dict(orient='index')).to_dict()
```

However, I keep getting a dictionary structured as:

```
{Name: {Methane:{"Quantity":#}, CO2:{"Quantity":#}, Other:{"Quantity":#}}
```

Any guidance on how to adjust my approach would be much appreciated! Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `pivot` the convert to dict:

```
>>> df.pivot(index='GreenhouseGas', columns='Name', values='Quantity').to_dict()

{'Chair': {'CO2': 0.4, 'Methane': 0.5, 'Other': 0.6},
 'House': {'CO2': 0.4, 'Methane': 0.2, 'Other': 0.3}}
```